# Not able to validate email textfield and not able to set fixed length for textfield in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Am Validating form in javaFX, i done with name validation but am not able to set **fixed length** for textfield and even am not able to validate the email also.[image: Screen Shot of my form]

Comment: Hint: Use a [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html#TextFormatter-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/karimsqualli96/f8d4c2995da8e11496ed **i take this as a reference** but still not able to get.Can you provide me any link or example?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? And what didn't work out for you?

Comment: **On KeyEvent i use this code**'txt_prn.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String oldValue, final String newValue) {
            int maxLength = 10;
            if (txt_prn.getText().length() > maxLength) {
                
                String s = txt_prn.getText().substring(0, maxLength);
                txt_prn.setText(s);
            }
        }
    });' and it works for me @ItachiUchiha;